# Running Docker and Github Actions Error Command not Found

Tags: docker, macos, github-actions, cicd

i have project to automating deploy my docker when new commit in github.
I have been running docker in mac, and this my error i got :

[error in github actions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IF5HW.png)

```
Run docker build . --file Dockerfile --flask-webyogixyz2345
  docker build . --file Dockerfile --flask-webyogixyz2345
  shell: /bin/zsh {0}
/Users/runner/work/_temp/acce643b-8828-43ba-94ea-b7c7b4c8f4ab:1: command not found: docker
Error: Process completed with exit code 127.
```

and this my script in github actions

```
name: Docker Image CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "new-feature" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "new-feature" ]

defaults:
  run:
    shell: zsh {0}
   

jobs:

  build:

    runs-on: macos-latest

    steps:
    
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Build the Docker image
      run: docker build . --file Dockerfile --flask-webyogixyz2345
```

can someone help me to solve this error ? thank youuu

no error in my github actions

Comment: docker build tools are not found. Probably you will need to install docker on the build runner first.

Comment: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/25777#discussioncomment-3249229

Comment: [Colima](https://github.com/abiosoft/colima) (Container runtimes on macOS) has been added to the macOs runner as stated [here](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues/2150). It's informed on the [macos runner image configurations](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/macos/macos-12-Readme.md). More informations and workarounds can be found [here](https://blog.netnerds.net/2022/11/docker-macos-github-actions/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in different discussions on the Github Community: [Source 1](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/25777#discussioncomment-3249229) + [Source](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues/17#issuecomment-614726536)

> Unfortunately, the docker community licensing is such that **we are not able to install the docker for mac on our hosted runners**.  We have had some discussions with Docker about doing this but they have held firm on their request that using Docker on a service requires an enterprise license and docker enterprise is not at all supported on macOS.

*Note that for Windows, Microsoft holds the license for Docker Enterprise on Windows so we do not have any issues there and for Linux we use a specific build of Docker for Linux that is built and maintained by Azure.*

---

Fortunately, as explained [in this issue](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues/2150), [Colima](https://github.com/abiosoft/colima) (a container runtimes on macOS) has been added to the [macos runner image](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/macos/macos-12-Readme.md).

Which allows you to use docker commands, as below, on a macos runner:

```
jobs:
   job:
     runs-on: macos-latest
     steps:
       - run: |
            brew install docker
            colima start
            docker run -e [...]
```

More informations and workarounds can be found [here](https://blog.netnerds.net/2022/11/docker-macos-github-actions/)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to install docker on the runner. You can create a bash script that will install docker whichever way you would like but this is a docker supported git actions workflow you can use to set up docker:

```
  - name: Set up QEMU
    uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v2
  - name: Set up Docker Buildx
    uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2
  - name: Login to DockerHub
    uses: docker/login-action@v2
    with:
      username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USER }}
      password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_TOKEN }}
```

Answer (score 0):

An Alternative approach based on the theory of **'Write once, run anywhere'** -

I tried the solution suggested in the [article](https://blog.netnerds.net/2022/11/docker-macos-github-actions/) shared by @GuiFalourd, I added following lines in my app-ci.yml

```
run: |
        brew install docker
        colima start
        docker-compose up -d
```

I still ran into the error `docker-compose: command not found` and also the build time included **installing docker every time**, taking almost **2 minutes** in that single step. It definitely is a **performance issue** in real time.

Hence as it is github action, where the build can afford to be platform independent, I just changed to ubuntu rather than macOs as follows

[image]

and my run command went back to single line of execution -

[image]

It worked like a charm for me.